# Return exception in background worker calling another method

Tags: c#, exception

What's the most elegant way of returning exceptions in a background worker that runs another method but that method can also be run outside a background worker?

For example below is a really simplified example where SomeMethod() raises an error. I need to display the error which is fine if not in the backgroundworker but display it at some point.

```
private void WorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  getMethod = SomeMethod();
}

private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{

}

private List<SomeVar> SomeMethod()
{

  try
  {
    throw new DivideByZeroException();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    //Return Exceptions from here to Worker_RunWorkerCompleted
    //Otherwise show message if not in bgw
    var result = ModernDialog.ShowMessage("Error occurred...." + e.Message, "ErrorTitle", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
   }
}
```

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719970/backgroundworker-thread-must-be-sta) shows how to pass the error back if the error is raised inside the DoWork method but would like some advice on the best method in my example.

Ideally, I would like the ability to call `SomeMethod()` both inside and outside a backgroundworker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, since `SomeMethod` doesn't know how it should properly handle the exception it simply shouldn't catch it.  It should just let it bubble up.

If it happens to be called from a BGW then that worker can grab the `e.Error` property to look at it and handle that case appropriately.  If someone else calls it then they can catch the exception and act appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the reasons tasks have come to forefront as the preferred way to do threading in .net as [exception handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) + scheduling is baked in.