# released project produces error "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this" when creating bitmap in a DLL

Tags: c#, vb.net, release

I have a project that when debugging works perfectly fine and has everything correctly checked into TFS. I get the above error message when the released project calls the dll. The main project is in vb too

here is the stack trace
[stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iyxvx.png)

Error causing line of code at the beginning of the for each loop- `Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile(targetPath + "Copy-2.png"));`

Most of DLL's code -

```
    public Dictionary<string, MemoryStream> CreateW2FromBitmap(List<Employee> info, Employer employerInfo, bool fourPerPage)
    {
        var targetPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "..\\..\\" + "W2Images\\"));

        StringFormat rightAlign = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip);
        StringFormat centerAlign = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip);
        PdfPTable imageTable = new PdfPTable(2) { WidthPercentage = 82 };

        imageTable.DefaultCell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        imageTable.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        rightAlign.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
        centerAlign.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

        var brushColor = Brushes.Black;
        var W2ImageDictionary = new Dictionary<string, MemoryStream>();
        var font = new System.Drawing.Font("Courier", 12);
        var document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 0, 0, 10, 0);

        foreach (var property in info)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile(targetPath + "Copy-2.png"));
            MemoryStream tempImageStream = new MemoryStream();

            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, tempImageStream);
            var employeeCityStateZipCode = CityStateZipDelimiter(property.CityStateZip);
            var employerCityStateZipCode = CityStateZipDelimiter(employerInfo.CityStateZip);

            document.Open();
            writer.CloseStream = false;

            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 1:
                        bmp = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile(targetPath + "Copy-2.png"));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        bmp = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile(targetPath + "Copy-2.png"));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        bmp = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile(targetPath + "Copy-B.png"));
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        bmp = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile(targetPath + "Copy-B.png"));
                        break;
                }
```

Comment: Is the calling thread STA? What kind of project is the calling project (WPF? Winforms? ASP.NET? Something else?)? Can you include the stack trace of the exception in your post?

Comment: I added a stack trace for the call, but I only get this issue when running the app and not when running from within visual studio. I'm pretty sure the DLL was initially a WPF, but now is a class library with zero wpf functionality. The main project is a form and the images are stored within a folder in the main project

Comment: It is a WPF exception.  The exception occurs in a method named EmailReport(), it is called from a BackgroundWorker.  The code in the snippet has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BackgroundWorker thread must be STA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719970/backgroundworker-thread-must-be-sta)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The fix is changing where the images are stored. They were within the main app's folder. Hope this helps anyone in the future

`Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\Copy-2.png));`